# Issue with fetchType.Lazy...!

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to annotation based Transaction management. I am developing web application with spring 3.1, Hibernate 3.2.
I am have some issues with @Transactional.
I am going to load POJO which having set of child as below:
Parent class is DealerMaster that has set of DealerMember so I declared as

**in DealerMaster:**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "dealerMaster")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    public Set<DealerMember> getDealerMembers() {
        return this.dealerMembers;
    }
```

and i am using my HibernateUtil class to execute any query, so I am using load method:

```
public static Object loadObject(Session paramSession, Object paramObject)
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {       
      paramObject = paramSession.load(paramObject.getClass(), getId(paramObject));
    }
    catch (HibernateException localHibernateException)
    {
      setErrorMessage(paramObject, localHibernateException.getMessage());
      localHibernateException.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I the problem is my load method runs successfully but when move courser on paramObject it shows :

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

and all values are accessible at service layer only when i try to access it at controller side it throw error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.lbt.model.DealerMaster.dealerMember, no session or session was closed
```

When i googled on same issue I found that this related to lazy loading but i tried as lazy = false also fetchType.Eager but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand one thing about LazyInitialzation exception .It occurs when hibernate is unable to initialize object that have be set to fetch lazy and it mostly happens when session is closed on an object that contains sets of other objects that are set to lazy fetch.

While setting fetch to EAGER works, it might not work in some cases when there is hierarchy of objects involved.
For example: Users-->Contain set of Roles and Roles---> Contain set of Permissions.
NOw if all are on lazy fetch. IF I get user object and close session and then try to get roles out of it, I will get exception.If I set fetch eager for role in user POJO, still I get that exception because role POJO contains permission which is on lazy fetch.

So either set all in hierarchy to EAGER(have performance issues but will work).
OR close session after you have finished working on object(keeping lazy fetch).

Things will work :)

Comment: thanks for this key information, But I am trying to load parent POJO with set of child using Lazy fetchType, still getting invocationException as mentioned above. Still I am able to get all child record in service class only and not able to at controller or jsp. Is there any configuration or other way to get return POJO from service to controller with parent-child?

Comment: That is strange..if you are able to get all child records in service class,how come you aren't getting it in controller class. Re-apply the same strategy of service class for getting parent object for controller class also... Tell me you service class strategy to get parent object..